# Xcode Swift 3 data wont post to Firebase

Tags: ios, firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database

For some reason, this code is not posting to Firebase. I have tried several variations but nothing is posting.

Whenever I run this code, the output in the console is,

> 2017-02-07 11:42:14.378 NeedAMovie?[3394] 
>   [Firebase/Database][I-RDB03812] setValue: or removeValue: at
>   /movies/-KcP5FyUnpM9drNz3vsd failed: permission_denied.

DataService Class:

```
import Foundation
import Firebase

let URL_BASE = FIRDatabase.database().reference()

class DataSevice {

    static let ds = DataSevice()

    private var _REF_BASE = URL_BASE
    private var _REF_POSTS = URL_BASE.child("movies")

    var REF_BASE: FIRDatabaseReference{
        return _REF_BASE
    }

    var REF_POSTS: FIRDatabaseReference{
        return _REF_POSTS
    }

}
```

Part where i have code to post:

```
@IBAction func postBtn(_ sender: Any) {

    if(self.caption.text != ""){
        vars.caption = self.caption.text
    }

    if let img = imgView.image, imageSelected {
        let urlStr = "https://post.imageshack.us/upload_api.php"
        let url = URL(string: urlStr)!
        let imgData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img, 0.2)!
        let keyData = "AEHKLRSU485b1b4e7ca86c9fdcede4064b55d66b".data(using: .utf8)!  // key removed for sake of privacy
        let keyJSON = "json".data(using: .utf8)!

        Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
            multipartFormData.append(imgData, withName: "fileupload", fileName:"image", mimeType: "image/jpg")
            multipartFormData.append(keyData, withName: "key")
            multipartFormData.append(keyJSON, withName: "format")
        }, to: url, encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in
            switch encodingResult {
            case .success(let upload, _, _):
                upload.responseJSON { response in
                    if let info = response.result.value as? [String: AnyObject],
                        let links = info["links"] as? [String: AnyObject],
                        let imgLink = links["image_link"] as? String {
                        self.postToFirebase(imgLink)
                    }
                }
            case.failure(_): break
            }
        })
    }
    else{
        self.makeAlert("Missing Fields", msg: "In order to post you must include a Picture and a Caption")
    }
}

func postToFirebase(_ imgUrl: String?){

    if let description = self.caption.text , description != "" {

        if let title = self.movieTitle.text , title != ""{

            let post: Dictionary<String, AnyObject>  = [
                "title": title as AnyObject,
                "caption": description as AnyObject,
                "category": vars.category as AnyObject,
                "imageURL": imgUrl! as AnyObject
            ]

            print(post)
            //over here add this post to the users post array

            var fpost = DataSevice.ds.REF_BASE.child("movies").childByAutoId()

            fpost.setValue(post)

            self.movieTitle.text = ""
            self.caption.text = ""
            self.imgView.image = UIImage(named: "")
            self.imageSelected = false
        }

    }
    else{
        print("didnt work")
    }

}
```

The `postToFirebase` method is where the actual posting is being done. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is correct. The problem is Firebase database permission. Your database not allowed to post.
Go to Firebase console. On left side, select Database button. On right side, you will see Data, Rules, Usage, Backups. Select Rules, and change values to :

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "true",
    ".write": "true"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks it Worked!